# Prove by Natural deduction that $\lnot\exists xP(x)\rightarrow\forall x\lnot P(x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have the following problem:

> Prove by Natural deduction in First Order Logic that
>
> $\lnot\exists xP(x)\rightarrow\forall x \lnot P(x)$

I tried to prove it using the Contradiction Theorem but I got stuck.

Probably I am missing something.

Comment: Not sure what axioms you are allowed, but I would just switch the quantifier and remove the resulting double negation.

Answer (score 2):

Under the premise $\neg\exists x P(x)$, assume $P(x)$ and follow from this contradiction.

Comment: Is simply switching quantifiers not allowed, i.e.  $\exists x:P(x) \equiv \neg\forall x:\neg P(x)$?

Comment: @Dan: I assumed the problem was to prove some aspect of quantifier switching and that's why I didn't use it.

Comment: Yes, of course. I've always thought the above equivalence was the definition of $\exists$.

Comment: In intuitionistic logic it isn't, and indeed $\lnot\forall xP(x)\to \exists x \lnot P(x)$ cannot be.proved, analogous to the way $\lnot\lnot p\to p$ is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need to use Contradiction Theorem!

The following is a derivation of the formula $\lnot\exists x \, P(x) \to \forall x \, \lnot P(x)$ in first-order natural deduction without using the rules RAA (*reductio ad absurdum*) and EFQ (*ex falso quodlibet*):

[image: derivation in first-order natural deduction]

This means that the formula $\lnot \exists x \, P(x) \to \forall x \, \lnot P(x)$ is provable not only in first-order classical logic, but also in first-order intuitionistic (and minimal) logic.